# Ado.Net and BigInteger result to an invalid cast exception to Int64

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, ado.net, biginteger

I have a simple SQL query to execute in Ado.Net. It has one parameter, a **BigInteger**.

```
public int MyMethod(BigInteger executionId)
{
    int status = -1;
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        var command = new SqlCommand("select ... where execution_id=@execution_id", connection) { CommandType = CommandType.Text };
        var parameterExecutionId = new SqlParameter("@execution_id", executionId) { SqlDbType = SqlDbType.BigInt };
        command.Parameters.Add(parameterExecutionId);
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                status = Convert.ToInt32(reader["status"]);
            }
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
    return status;    
}
```

When I am running this code I have on the **ExecuteReader** this exception:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' 
occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Failed to convert parameter 
value from a BigInteger to a Int64.
```

The database does have the **execution_id** column set to **bigint**.

What is wrong?

Comment: What value are you submitting with that parameter? What type is executionId?

Comment: Where is `executionId` declared? What type is it?

Comment: BigInteger executionId, it is the parameter of the method that has the code posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BigInt` does not correspond to `BigInteger`. It corresponds to `long`/`Int64`. You should probably remove all `BigInteger` usages from your business code and use `long`. ADO.NET does not understand `BigInteger`.

Comment: Thank you @usr, it so not intuitive that BigInt and BigInteger are not corresponding. It works with long as you mentionned. Thank you

Comment: Yes. The name BigInt is from the days where SQL Server was not designed to fit .NET (because it did not exist). BigInteger was added in .NET 4 and is a math-style unlimited integer. Now you at least know the historical context.

Comment: Thank you @usr for the explication

Answer (score 1):

Your BigInteger is a complex type in System.Numerics, this does not map to SQL BigInt.  As a general rule, usually when mapping C# types to SQL DB types its a base type such as long, int, int64, string... in this case your secondary error message suggest Int64.  If you decide keep BigInteger as the parameter you pass in then you should Cast that to a long inside your Method.  You can also specify the SQL Type in the instantiation of SqlParameter.

```
public int MyMethod(BigInteger executionId)
{
    int status = -1;
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        var command = new SqlCommand("select ... where execution_id=@execution_id", connection)     { CommandType = CommandType.Text };

        //BigInteger to Int64 conversion long and Int64 is the same type
        long execId = (long) executionId;

        var parameterExecutionId = new SqlParameter("@execution_id", SqlDbType.BigInt, execId);
        command.Parameters.Add(parameterExecutionId);
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                status = Convert.ToInt32(reader["status"]);
            }
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
    return status;    
}
```